# Burger Riddle, Can you solve it?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation, family

There once were 2 mothers and 2 daughters. One day they went to eat burgers. Each woman ate only one WHOLE burger. Yet only 3 burgers are eaten! Perplexed? Unravel this mind-boggling riddle!

Comment: I would have a solution involving canibalism.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is as follows:

> There was a grandmother a mother and a daughter!
>  
>  There is still two mothers and two daughters but there is only 3 people!
>  
>  3 generations, 4 people!

Comment: I'd recommend waiting longer than three minutes for someone else to answer before posting the answer yourself. Also, please do not rollback formatting edits.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "rollback for matting edits"?

Comment: Someone edited your answer to include a spoiler tag (which answers should always have, to avoid spoiling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves). You then rolled back the edit a couple of hours ago and removed the spoiler tag. You may well have done it by accident, I'm just letting you know.